# How do I extended the validity of a client certificate?

Tags: azure, certificate

I have this script for creating a root and client certificate for azure point to site vpn connection.

I have extended the root certificate validity to 5 years but when I generate my client certificate it only had 1 year validity.

Here the powershell script I've used.

Root

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -KeySpec Signature `
-Subject "RootCert-AzureP2SVPN" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable `
-HashAlgorithm sha256 -KeyLength 2048 `
-CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyUsageProperty Sign -KeyUsage CertSign -NotAfter(Get-Date).AddYears(5)
```

Client

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -DnsName P2SChildCert -KeySpec Signature `
-Subject "ClientCert-AzureP2SVPN" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable `
-HashAlgorithm sha256 -KeyLength 2048 `
-CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" `
-Signer $cert -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2")
```

Answer (score 0):

```powershell
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "RDS.Contoso.local" `
  -DnsName "RDS.Contoso.com", "www.contoso.com" `
  -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My" -KeyAlgorithm RSA `
  -KeyLength 2048 -KeyExportPolicy Exportable `
  -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(5)
```

Supported by 2016 Server/win10 or Higher